# 'for Each objDrive in colDrives' creating function syntax error

Tags: vbscript

I am trying to create a .vbs that will check is a dvd drive exists (if objdrive.drivetype= 4) while ignoring other drives such as hard drives (else if cdrive = 1 then -no statement- ect.).
However this line is causing me grief: "For Each objDrive in colDrives". When it exists it causes a syntax error, yet when it is removed it causes an error saying "object required: objdrive". The script uses a hta/vbs hybrid that offers the user to cancel the search for media, and this is achieved by using a function so putting this in a sub and calling this would be useless. Here is my code, please help.

```
Set shell=CreateObject("wscript.shell")
Set objShell = Wscript.CreateObject("WScript.Shell") 
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set colDrives = objFSO.Drives
For Each objDrive in colDrives

if objdrive.drivetype= 4 then 
select case 1

case 1

if objdrive.isready then
'continue statement here
else
select case 2

case 2

with HTABox("#F2F2F2", 115, 300, 700, 400)
.document.title = "Waiting..."
.msg.innerHTML = "Waiting for playable media...<b>"

end with
function HTABox(sBgColor, h, w, l, t)
Dim IE, HTA


randomize : nRnd = Int(1000000 * rnd)
sCmd = "mshta.exe ""javascript:{new " _
   & "ActiveXObject(""InternetExplorer.Application"")" _
   & ".PutProperty('" & nRnd & "',window);" _
   & "window.resizeTo(" & w & "," & h & ");" _
   & "window.moveTo(" & l & "," & t & ")}"""

with CreateObject("WScript.Shell")
.Run sCmd, 1, False
do until .AppActivate("javascript:{new ") : WSH.sleep 10 : loop
end with ' WSHShell

For Each IE In CreateObject("Shell.Application").windows
If IsObject(IE.GetProperty(nRnd)) Then
  set HTABox = IE.GetProperty(nRnd)
  IE.Quit
  HTABox.document.title = "Waiting"
  HTABox.document.write _
           "<HTA:Application contextMenu=no border=thin " _
         & "minimizebutton=no maximizebutton=no sysmenu=no />" _
         & "<body scroll=no style='background-color:" _
         & sBgColor & ";font:normal 10pt Arial;" _
         & "border-Style:normal;border-Width:0px'" _
         & "onbeforeunload='vbscript:if (done.value or cancel.value) then " _
         & "window.event.cancelBubble=false:" _
         & "window.event.returnValue=false:" _
         & "cancel.value=false: done.value=false:end if'>" _
         & "<input type=hidden id=done   value=false>" _
     & "<input type=hidden id=cancel value=false>" _
         & "<center><span id=msg>&nbsp;</span><br>" _
     & "&nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp; &nbsp;<center><input type=button id=btn1 value=Cancel
         ' "_
         & "onclick=self.close><center></body>"
exit function
End If
Next

MsgBox "HTA window not found."
wsh.quit

End Function
end select
end select
else if objdrive.drivetype = 1 then
else if objdrive.drivetype = 2 then
else if objdrive.drivetype = 3 then
else if objdrive.drivetype = 5 then
end if
```

Answer (score 1):

The syntax error is most likely caused by the missing `Next` keyword that would close the loop. I think the conditional `if objdrive.isready then` is missing a closing `End If` too (between the two `End Select`). Add the missing keywords and the error should go away.

However, you're doing this whole thing upside down. Why are you creating an HTA on the fly from a VBScript? Just write the HTA and embed whatever VBScript code you need in it. See [this tutorial](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee692768.aspx) for an introduction. Also, I would **strongly** recommend avoiding nested function definitions. They will cause you maintenance headaches at some point and they're not even generally allowed in VBScript. And what are your `Select` statements supposed to do? A construct

```
Select Case 1
  Case 1
    'instruction
End Select
```

is utterly pointless, because there is no selection in the first place. It's the exact same as running the instruction directly. Another thing to avoid are empty actions in conditionals. They just make your code harder to read and to maintain without generating you any benefit.

Comment: Thank you. I know that it is a mess, i just like to push boundaries and see what is possible and what can be made possible.

Answer (score 0):

Its possible your issue may be due to the Upper Case D in "objDrive" in your For statement and then you later reference the name with a lower case "d" objdrive.isready within the loop.  You may want to declare 'Option Explicit' at the top to find all undeclared variables.

Can you test the below code and see if it performs properly.

```
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
For Each objDrive in objFSO.Drives
    If objDrive.DriveType = 4 Then 
        If objDrive.IsReady Then
            MsgBox "The appropriate media is inserted and ready for access"
        Else
            MsgBox "The Drive Is Not Ready"
        End If
    End If
Next
```

Also, I'm not sure the code snippet you provided is your full code but there appear to be several missing End statements.  If so, these may also cause you problems.

Comment: VBScript identifiers are case-insensitive, so no, that is not the issue.